# Javascript regex get only page number from URL

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-replace

i have URL like 
https://example.com/my-list/page/35/?a=45&b=56

I want to get page number using regex that is after /page/ in url,
the result i want is 35

Comment: Bad Question. Please read the how to ask

Comment: why using regular expressions?

Comment: @assembler i think regular expressions is shortest and best way.. and i want to learn more about this.

Comment: @vishalsharma I think the shortest and more understandable way here is not through regular expressions.

Comment: @assembler ok can you please suggest best way to achieve result ? and if possible please give me example for that. thanks

Comment: Maybe not the best way, but a functional way, you could use string methods such as substring.

Comment: `"https://example.com/my-list/page/35/?a=45&b=56".split('page/')[1].split('/')[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's 2 easy ways you could do it using RegEx:

**The first way:**

```
var s = "https://example.com/my-list/page/35/?a=45&b=56";
//  First way uses capture groups based on what comes before the page number: "/page/"
s.match(/\/page\/(\d*)/)[1]; // "35"
```

**The second way:**

```
//  The second involves using capture grouping based on the search param that appears to follow.
//  However, this way might not be ideal as you may extend the URI and make a major change that would then require an edit to this. Of course, that could happen with the previous as well.

s.match(/(\d*)(?=\/\?)/)[0]  //  "35"
```

You can also `split` the string, and then use regex to grab just the beginning of the string:

```
s.split("/page/")[1].match(/^\d*/);  //  "35"
```

You could also simply split the whole string based on the most common element: "/". If your URI pattern is always the same, then this is probably one of the most simply and easy to read solutions. However, if the URI pattern changes to have more fields, then you may have to adjust the index number.

```
s.split("/")[5]  //  "35"
```

You could also use `substr` based on the index of "page". The problem with this is the page number might be 1 digit, 2 digits, or more:

```
s.substr(s.indexOf("page/")+5, 2)  //  "35"
//  +5 due to length of phrase i use
```

You could use the `substr` and `index` grab the string you want, having the page number at the very start of the string. Then use regex to pull the number and have it rest at 0 index. This might be more practical in case, for whatever reason, there is no page number. For instance, the user ends up at the "page" index base.

```
s.substr(s.indexOf("page/")+5).match(/^\d*/)[0]  //  35
```

Comment: @vishalsharma not a problem. as aforementioned, i'll spend a minute posting some alternatives as well, just so you can get a feeling for how there's always different ways to do things in JS and sometimes, the way you find first isn't best for what you want to achieve overall.

Comment: i tried to achieve that by like this
s.replace(/.*page\/(d)*/g,""); 
but i stuck

Comment: How are you using `replace` and what is your expected result? What I mean is, `.replace` doesn't actually change the string; it simply `returns` the result. So if you wanted to change `s` to that, you'd need to do `s = s.replace(/.*page\/(d)*/g,"");` which would change `s` to `"35/?a=45&b=56"`

Comment: yes you are right result was "35/?a=45&b=56" and i stuck after that.
here the "Way 1" is good and will work in case if there is any change in URL like
'https://example.com/my-list/page/35/param1/param2/?a=45&b=56'

Comment: @vishalsharma You say you're stuck, what is it you're trying to achieve next?

Comment: I stuck when i was trying replace method and answer was  "35/?a=45&b=56" after that i got stuck. 
here the "Way 1" is good and will work in case if there is any change in URL like 'example.com/my-list/page/35/param1/param2/?a=45&b=56'

Comment: Were you meaning something like this: `s.replace(/\/page\/\d*/, "/page/99")`? |OR| `s.replace(/\/page\/\d.*/, "/page/99/")`?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress can also use another url format where page number is stored in url query `paged` parameter so the safest solution would be to cover both url formats. Another problem is that on first page of any archive you will not find page number in the url so we need to cover that case also.

**Here is the simple function that will work for every case:**

```
function getPageFromUrl( url ) {
    const match = url.match(/(?:\/page\/|[?&]paged=)([1-9]\d*)/)
    if ( match ) {
        return Number(match[1]);
    }
    return 1;
}
```